# Docker rm command throws error when using $()

Tags: docker

I'm on a Windows 10 Enterprise OS and Docker ver 18.09.

From the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#remove-a-link-specified-with---link-on-the-default-bridge-network) docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) gives an error:

unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker rm --help'

I can remove the containers one at a time with the Docker container rm command just fine, but I wanted to know why i'm getting this error.

Comment: I hope you are trying to delete all running or not running containers, if this is the case then my solution could help you.

Comment: The docker command assumes you are using a bash shell. It will not work from a command prompt. Are you able to use bash in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assuming here that you want to delete all docker's container ids only. ***so please DO NOT run this in case you don't want to delete all containers.***

***Following will ONLY and ONLY help*** when you want to delete all container ids in docker(tested this on Ubuntu system):

```
docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to abandon Docker for the time being. I'm running a NativeScript app and its not compatible with the Android emulation. I don't really need it, but I thought I should learn how to use Docker.

Comment: `xargs docker rm` will throw an error if there is nothing to delete. But `xargs -r docker rm` works fine without error if nothing to delete OR there is containers to delete.