# Removing docker container list throws error in commandpromt

Tags: docker, cmd, windows-10, docker-for-windows

I am using `Docker on windows` and trying to remove all containers with names starting with 'test' using below command

```
 docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q -f name=test)
```

It throws exception

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker rm --help'.
```

I also tried the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045791/docker-rm-command-throws-error-when-using) on stack overflow.

```
docker ps -a -q -f name=test | xargs docker rm
```

Here I am getting an exception

> 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Those are Unix Bourne shell commands, and might not work in a Windows environment that's not trying to simulate it.

Comment: @ Davis Is there any alternative windows command

Answer (score 0):

To remove docker image first you need to stop the container that is attached to that image. After doing that you can simply run

To Stop all container

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)

docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

This will remove all docker images from your system. If you are not in root you need to use 
`sudo docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)`

Comment: I am using Docker on windows
When I execute the command I am getting error 
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker container stop --help'.

Comment: To simple clear everything do:


docker system prune --all
Everything means:

all stopped containers
all networks not used by at least one container
all images without at least one container associated to them
all build cache

Comment: docker system prune  doesnot have an filter for name